# How to add attribute(s) to Wordpress shortcode (OOP style) in a proper way?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, shortcode

How do I add attributes (in this case a language) in proper to a class in Wordpress for use within shortcodes?

Lets say we have class called `FormHandler`

```
class FormHandler {
    private $language = 'en';

    public function __construct($language = null) {
        if ($language !== null) {
            $this->language = $language;
        }
    }

    public function display_form() {
        if ($this->language === 'se' {
            return 'return html for the swedish form';
        }
        else {
            return 'return html for the english form';
        }
    } 

}

add_shortcode( 'contactform', array('FormHandler', 'display_form') );
```

In the wordpress I want to add the shortcode in the content something like

```
[contactform lang=en] or [contactform lang=en] based on the language.
```

I COULD use global variables to get the actual language, but that does not seem like the proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Why can't you just use [`get_locale`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale)?

Comment: The language was just an example, I was curious about how to handle attributes/objects/shortcodes in WP undependelty of what the attributes are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to accept an argument in your `display_form` function to receive the attributes passed in from the shortcode.

```
public function display_form( $attrs )
{
  // you should have your defaults here
  $defaults = array(
    'lang' => $this->language
  );

  $args = wp_parse_args( $attrs, $defaults );

  // now extract so you can use the variable directly
  extract( $args );

  if ( $lang == 'se' ) 
  {
    $html = 'Swedish';
  } else 
  {
    $html = 'English';
  }

  return $html;
}
```

Now you can use the shortcode - but don't forget the quotation marks round the language: `[contactform lang="se"]`